# ¿Has the proof of Theorem 1.21 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin a meaning?

Tags: analysis, advice

I did the proof of this theorem a slightly different some time ago, but, I really forgot almost everything and the problem is that, I understand the body of the proof, but, I don't understand why he use those numbers and inequalities (Despite on the fact that they works). I think is the same for some other proofs of the book.

My question is about, how much background has the proof?, to get those expressions

Here is the proof

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you pls show us more details?

Comment: Can you type the theorem? Explain more clearly what issue you have with it? Rudin is famous for creating expressions out of thin air that magically work, without much context.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I taked the picture but, I forgot to post it

Comment: My problem is, everytime he defines a expression, I don't get where he gets that

Comment: Please put it right-side up.